# Meaning of the phrase "difference is transparent"

Tags: meaning, phrases

Does  "difference is transparent" mean something like invisible, not apparent?

For example: "Like a char device, each block device is accessed through a filesystem node, and the difference between them is transparent to the user."

Does the above line mean that user doesn't see any difference between the char and block devices?

Comment: "Transparent to the user" is an idiom meaning "the user can't tell the difference".

Comment: Yes, it does mean that the user cannot see the difference between the two. Theoretically, if you look at something that is truly transparent, you don't see it. _Transparent_ is often used in this meaning in IT-related environments.

Comment: Good question. This type of figurative *transparent* can have either of two completely opposite senses - ***invisible*** (user cannot discern any difference), and ***clear, obvious*** (user cannot fail to be aware of the difference). But in your specific context it's virtually certain the former is the intended sense.

Comment: I'll add that "transparent to the user" is a mild abuse of the term "transparent", as used elsewhere in computerdom, but one that is generally accepted.

Comment: @HotLicks May I ask why you think it's an abuse of the term?

Comment: @Hot Licks "Transparent to X" is an idiom meaning "obvious to X".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth according to the other answers (as well as from my understanding), it is the opposite of that meaning here!

Comment: My interpretation of [*How can we claim both that sexual **difference is transparent** and that man and woman represent a mystery to each other?*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sexual+difference+is+transparent%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is that this usage is the ***clear, obvious*** sense. It doesn't make much sense to understand it as ***invisible***.

Comment: I'm talking about the general usage. And the word 'difference' has not been included.

Comment: @Edwin: But *both* usages/meanings are "commonplace/general".

Comment: @Lavya - Elsewhere "transparent" refers to a component that sits between two endpoints and relays data/events back and forth in such a way that the component's presence cannot be detected.  The "mild abuse" is using "transparent" to mean that a *difference* between two components cannot be detected.  While this slight shift in sense might seem obvious to someone analyzing the English words, it could easily befuddle some literalist programmers.

Comment: Now I'm getting confused (about the general usage of the phrase. thankfully the sentence in question is transparent) :)

Comment: I'd want '**Here**, "the difference is transparent to the user" means  "the user can't tell the difference".

Comment: We must remember that the above discussion is in the context of computers and data communications technology, not general English, and certainly not (Heaven forbid!!) sex.  (These are programmers talking, after all.)

Comment: @Lavya: Don't be misled into thinking that somehow tacking on *transparent **to** [someone who might otherwise detect a difference]* inherently removes any ambiguity by forcing the "invisible" interpretation. Have a look at real-world instances of [*(something obvious) is transparent to anyone.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is+transparent+to+anyone%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @Hot Licks That's a particular example given by OP after a more general request. 'Does' does not mean 'can'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - "Transparent to the user" is an idiom meaning "the user can't tell the difference".  "Transparent to the grammarian" may mean something else entirely, but that's not the subject under discussion.

Comment: @Hot Licks: It just so happens that in computerland we have a lot of "black boxes", and it's often useful to swap one black box for a different one that does *exactly* the same job, but *internally* goes about it in a different way. Consequently the "not visible" sense is more likely, but this doesn't imply computer users have a "different" idiom. It's just that they're particularly likely to use one of the two senses more than the other one, because it represents something they often need to refer to.

Comment: @FF Can you show me in [these 3 dictionaries](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/transparent) where an obvious metaphorical usage with the sense 'hard / impossible to discern // easy to miss' is given? The metaphorical usage 'obvious / easily detected' is clearly listed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for the suggestion. The very first example is the totally opposite use of the word/phrase. I wonder if English is a particularly mixed up language or all languages have similar amounts of ambiguities. At phonological level at least many other languages seem much less ambiguous. Of course there are other things about English which are nice.

Comment: @Edwin: Gimmie a break! Are you seriously suggesting I need to find dictionary support for the idea that, for example, [*transparent to the electorate*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22transparent+to+the+electorate%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is normal use of English? (And that it would almost always mean ***easily seen/understood***, obviously.)

Comment: This has been addressed before on [ELL (!)](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17693/what-is-the-correct-interpretation-of-transparent). The autoantonymic nature of 'transparent' is described, but so is the fact that the term easily confuses and needs to be adequately contextualised if not used in its more common general English sense. 'To find a dictionary definition meaning "unnoticeable", though, I had to go to a more specialized reference, the Computer Desktop Encyclopedia' (J.R.). OP's title is inadequate.

Comment: @FF I asked for the other usage. You say 'both usages/meanings are "commonplace/general" '. //// It could be that you thought I was addressing _you_ in a previous (un-@-ed) comment.

Comment: Could we have some responses in the answer box, not the comments, please?

Comment: @TimLymington It's dealt with probably as well as is possible on ELL at the above link. Doesn't this make it a duplicate? It's genref at best.

Comment: @Hot Licks '"Transparent to the user" is an idiom meaning "the user can't tell the difference". ' In that case, the question needs adjusting. OP asks in the first instance about the 'Meaning of the phrase “difference is transparent” ', not the claimed idiom (and I'm not sure whether the concept of register-specific idioms is widely accepted).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27409/discussion-on-question-by-lavya-meaning-of-the-phrase-difference-is-transparent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Transparent" is used in several senses.  The [most literal sense](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/transparent) is *Capable of transmitting light so that objects or images can be seen as if there were no intervening material*.  Ie, a piece of regular glass is "transparent".

The common figurative sense is quite the opposite: *easily understood; manifest; obvious*.

If one were to take literally the sentence "The senator's written statements are totally transparent" it would imply that you could not see them at all, but the figurative sense of the term (and it's antonym "opaque") is flipped 180 degrees, and that sentence means that the Senator's thoughts and intentions can be easily discerned.

Computers, on the other hand, take things pretty literally, and therefore "transparent" is typically used in the literal sense when speaking of computers and data communcations.  So if "Component X is transparent" then it's implied that the presence of "Component X" is not readily obvious, even though it may stand "in the way" of communications between two other components.

Similarly, saying that "the difference between X and Y is transparent to the user" implies that one can be substituted for the other without changing the "optical properties", as it were, of the overall system -- what you could see before you can still see.

It's not computer terminology that's screwed up, it's the rest of English.